# Quotient of $\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N}$ by a cyclic subgroup is isomorphic to itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-abelian-group

Consider the group $G=\Bbb Z^{(\Bbb N)}$, the direct sum of countably many $\Bbb Z$'s. (Thus $\Bbb Z^{(\Bbb N)}$ is free abelian of rank $| \Bbb N|$.) Let $a$ be any nonzero element of $G$. Then $<a>$ is an infinite cylcic subgroup of $G$, isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. I want to prove that $G/<a>$ is isomorphic to $G$, which seems obvious, but I don't know how to do. How do I have to do?

Comment: As stated, this is false. If you quotient by $\langle(2,0,0,\ldots)\rangle$, the quotient will be $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\oplus \bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @jgon Thanks. I was stupid

Comment: Given an infinite set $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ you could ask this question for $\langle a\rangle$ where $a = (a_i)$ such that $a_i = 0$ for $i\in S$ and $a_i = 1$ otherwise. Then it should be true.

Comment: @SantanaAfton It should also be true if you merely require that $a\ne kb$ for any $b\in G$, $k\in\Bbb{Z}$, $|k| > 1$. I think as long as you avoid creating torsion, this should be true.

Comment: @jgon I’m not sure I understand. Doesn’t your counterexample satisfy that condition? It seems like if any term in $a$ is not $0$ of $1$ then you’ll create torsion.

Comment: @SantanaAfton My $a$ is $2(1,0,\ldots)$, and thus doesn't satisfy my condition. However, I think e.g. $a=(2,3,0,0,\ldots)$ shouldn't create torsion. But I haven't thought it out very thoroughly right now.

Comment: @jgon I see. So, is the condition that the gcd of the nonzero terms is $1$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton That would be my guess, and perhaps I'll try to prove that later and write up an answer, but I haven't verified that properly yet.

Comment: $A^X$ denotes the unrestricted product so was very confusing. I corrected to the standard notation $A^{(X)}$ to denote the direct sum ($A^{\oplus X}$ is fine too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $a$ generates a maximal cyclic subgroup of $G=\Bbb{Z}^{\oplus \Bbb{N}}$ if for any other $b\in G$, $\langle a\rangle \subseteq \langle b\rangle$ implies $\langle b \rangle =\langle a \rangle$.

Then you can check that the following are equivalent

- $a$ generates a maximal cyclic subgroup of $G$,
- when $a=nb$, for $b\in G$, $n\in\newcommand\ZZ{\Bbb{Z}}\ZZ$, we have $n=\pm 1$,
- The greatest common divisor of the entries of $a$ is $1$.

> Then $G/\langle a \rangle \cong G$ if and only if $a$ generates a maximal cyclic subgroup.

*Proof.*

First suppose $a$ generates a maximal cyclic subgroup of $G$. We'll prove that in fact $G$ has a free basis containing $a$, and thus that, up to an automorphism of $G$, we can take $a$ to be $(1,0,0,\ldots)$. To see that such a free basis exists, note that since 
$a$ has finitely many nonzero entries (which we may assume to be $1,\ldots,N-1$ without loss of generality), it suffices to find a free basis for $\ZZ^N$ containing $a$, since that can be extended to a free basis for $G$ by taking the standard basis vectors $e_n$ for $n>N$. We're using $N$ rather than $N-1$, since the extra coordinate, where we know $a_N=0$, allows us a little more flexibility and cleaner formulas.

Now since the greatest common divisor of the entries of $a$ is $1$, we can find integers $b_1,\ldots, b_{N-1}$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_ib_i = 1.$$
Then choose $f_i= e_i -b_ie_N$ for $1\le i \le N-1$.

Now observe that $$a - \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_if_i = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_ib_i e_N = e_N.$$
Thus $\langle a,f_1,\ldots,f_{N-1}\rangle$ contains $e_N$, and thus also $e_i$ for all $1\le i\le N-1$, since $e_i=f_i+b_ie_N$. Hence $a,f_1,\ldots,f_{N-1}$ are $N$ elements of $\ZZ^N$ that generate $\ZZ^N$, and thus form a free basis, as desired.

Hence if $a$ generates a maximal cyclic subgroup of $G$, $G$ is the internal direct sum of $\langle a\rangle$ and a free subgroup isomorphic to $G$. Hence in this case, $G/\langle a \rangle \cong G$, as desired.

Now suppose $a$ doesn't generate a maximal cyclic subgroup. Then let $d$ be the greatest common divisor of the entries in $a$. Thus $a=db$, for some $b\in G$. Moreover, $b$ generates a maximal cyclic subgroup of $G$. But then $G\cong \langle b\rangle \oplus G'$, where $G'$ is a free subgroup isomorphic to $G$.

Hence 
$$G/\langle a\rangle \cong \left(\langle b\rangle /\langle a \rangle\right) \oplus G'\cong \ZZ/d\ZZ\oplus G.$$
Then since this group has nonzero torsion, it is not isomorphic to $G$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: If I take $a$ to have entries only distinct primes, e.g. $a = (2,3,5,\dots)$, it seems as though $\langle a\rangle$ should be maximal and it does not have finitely many nonzero entries.

Comment: @SantanaAfton, sure but it's also not an element of $G$

Comment: Oh, I misread “sum” as “product.” Okay!